# Searching by current date in MYSQL using JPA repository

Tags: java

I am using JPA Repository.

I need to search records by ID and Current Date.
Presently I am using

```
List<Allocation> findByIdAndDate(String Id , Date date);
```

I am sending current date at the time of method calling

Just like we have method

```
List<Entity> findByIdAndFlagTrue(String Id)
```

which by default searches for a true flag, 
So if there is any method of query building which searches for current date

Comment: Show us the code. Especially the code for `findByIdAndFlagTrue()`...

Comment: do you have date related column, if yes then add WHERE condition with respective format and do show some code for exact answers.

Comment: I want to write a code. Presently I am using 
Student findByIdAndDate(String Id , Date date)
I am sending Id and current date object by default